# Possible to require at least one attachment from the signer?

Tags: docusignapi

I need users to upload their company logo when they're signing the document. Is there a way to make this required so the user won't be able to complete signing unless they've uploaded one file.

If code references can use xml, I'll appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I believe the property is called `optional` and you would want to set it to false.  Your tab definition (in XML) should look something like this:

```
<signerAttachmentTabs>
    <signerAttachment>
        <tabLabel>TabName</tabLabel>
        <documentId>2</documentId>
        <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
        <recipientId>1234</recipientId>
        <xPosition>300</xPosition>
        <yPosition>250</yPosition>
        <scaleValue>3.1</scaleValue>
        ...         
        <optional>false</optional>
        ...
    </signerAttachment>
</signerAttachmentTabs>
```